# React + AWS Cognito + AWS Amplify Not able to authenticate the signed up user using Amplify (Auth)

Tags: reactjs, google-oauth, amazon-cognito, google-signin, aws-amplify

I am using ReactJS web framework along with AWS Cognito and Google signup for login functionality using AWS Amplify.

**Here is the code for that:**

```
import React from 'react'
import {Amplify,Auth } from 'aws-amplify'


const Amp = () => {
    Amplify.configure({
        Auth: {
            region: 'us-east-2',
            userPoolId: 'us-east-2_gD63AHLbv',
            userPoolWebClientId: '7kgfjpin3rpujpsgsc3tc2junt',
            oauth : {
                domain: '*****-app.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com',
                redirectSignIn: 'http://localhost:3000/google',
                redirectSignOut: 'http://localhost:3000/google',
                scope : ['email', 'openid', 'profile', 'phone', 'aws.cognito.signin.user.admin'],
                responseType: 'code'
            },
        }
    })
     
    const checks = async () => {
        try {
        const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
        console.log(user)
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("Error:",err)
        }
    }

return(
<div>
<button onClick={() => {
    Auth.federatedSignIn()
}}>Hosted UI Signin</button>

<br/>

<button onClick={() => {
    Auth.federatedSignIn({provider:'Google'})
}}>Google Signin</button>

<br/>
<button onClick={() => {
    Auth.signOut()
}}>Signout</button>
<br/>

<button onClick={checks}>Check</button>

</div>

);


}
export default Amp;
```

After running this code I am successfully getting the Hosted UI functionality and Google signup

**Sample page:**

[image]

**On clicking Hosted UI button above:**

[image]

**Google signup:**

[image]

On clicking my gmail account for login, I am successfully redirected to the specified redirectURI.
The gmail account which I clicked to signup is also stored in the specified Cognito user pool.

But, when I click on **"Check"** button to check whether the current logged-in user is authenticated or not.

It is giving out the error that the current user is not authenticated. I caught that error and displayed in the console

[image]

The same problem occurred for email and password signup.

How to authenticate the user and generate tokens after signing up through Hosted UI or Google signup?

Comment: You should only perform `Amplify.configure` once at the start of the app.

Comment: Thanks So, if I configure the amplify at the start of the app using the cli (it would create an app in the amplify) and then would the login authentication work ? and Is this a good practice of using this Amplify app in production too ? Thanks again

Answer (score -1):

You should only perform `Amplify.configure` once at the start of the app and not each time the component renders.

This code snippet [from the Amplify Social sign-in doc](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/social/q/platform/react-native/#setup-frontend) appears to do what you're trying to do:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Text, View, Linking, Button } from "react-native";

import { Amplify, Auth, Hub } from "aws-amplify";
import awsconfig from "./aws-exports";

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);

export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [customState, setCustomState] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = Hub.listen("auth", ({ payload: { event, data } }) => {
      switch (event) {
        case "signIn":
          setUser(data);
          break;
        case "signOut":
          setUser(null);
          break;
        case "customOAuthState":
          setCustomState(data);
      }
    });

    Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
      .then(currentUser => setUser(currentUser))
      .catch(() => console.log("Not signed in"));

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <Button
        title="Open Amazon"
        onPress={() =>
          Auth.federatedSignIn({
            provider: "LoginWithAmazon",
          })
        }
      />
      <Button title="Open Hosted UI" onPress={() => Auth.federatedSignIn()} />
      <Button title="Sign Out" onPress={() => Auth.signOut()} />
      <Text>{user && user.getUsername()}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Also look into using Amplify's `Authenticator` component ([doc](https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react-native/connected-components/authenticator/advanced)) in conjunction with the `useAuthenticator` hook. You can override the UI to get the appearance you want.